# No puedo utilizar el autocompletado de la API de Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Siguiendo un tutorial que encontré, he intentado crear un form que me permita buscar direcciones usando el autocompletado de la API de Google Maps.

El problema es que cuando intento escribir algo en el input, esto es lo que pasa:

[image: Cuando escribo, el texto "Se ha producido un error" aparece.]

Aquí os muestro una imagen del error que aparece en la consola:

[image: Google Maps JavaScript API error]

Intuyo que el problema tiene que ver con la API Key que Google me ha proporcionado. ¿Alguien sabe cuáles son los pasos exactos para usar la API? Creo que estoy haciendo algo mal relacionado con esto.

De todas formas, aquí os muestro el código HTML por si hubiese algo mal:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="auto-complete.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Add your Address</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
       <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
          onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" class="form-control">
       <div id="address">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="control-label">Street address</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="street_number" disabled="true">
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="control-label">Route</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="route" disabled="true">
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="control-label">City</label>
                <input class="form-control field" id="locality" disabled="true">
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-6"> 
                <label class="control-label">State</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true">
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="control-label">Zip code</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="postal_code" disabled="true">
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="control-label">Country</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="country" disabled="true">
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC-nw0r_GDDz2TFbu3W7GuajWxJdjZU-3U&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
<body>
</html>
```

Y aquí tenéis el código JavaScript:

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
      var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
      };
function initAutocomplete() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
        // location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
            {types: ['geocode']});
// When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
        // fields in the form.
        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
      }
function fillInAddress() {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
for (var component in componentForm) {
          document.getElementById(component).value = '';
          document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }
// Get each component of the address from the place details
// and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
          var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
          if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
          }
        }
      }
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
      function geolocate() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)  {
            var geolocation = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
              center: geolocation,
              radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
          });
        }
      }
```

Muchas gracias! Un saludo!

Comment: Hola! Este sitio es la versión En Español de SO. Si deseas mantener tu pregunta aquí, por favor usa el enlace Editar que está justo debajo y traduce su contenido y su título.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder. Ya está solucionado ;)

Comment: Podrías añadir la respuesta y marcarla como aceptada. Digo, para que otros en el futuro sepan qué hiciste  para solucionar tu problema

Comment: Perdona, me refería a que ya estaba solucionado lo del idioma.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa que tengas activada correctamente la libreria.
Ingresa a https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Despues da click en places y habilitala.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, con esto logré solucionarlo.

Comment: @jmartinezb marca la respuesta como aceptada :)